# Perceptron training rule, why multiply by x

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I was reading tom Mitchell's machine learning book and he mentioned the formula for perceptron training rule is

[image]

where

[image]

- [image] : training rate
- [image] : expected output
- [image] : actual output
- [image] : ith input

This implies that if [image] is very large then so is [image], but I don't understand the purpose of a large update when [image] is large

on the contrary, I feel like if there is a large [image] then the update should be small since a small fluctuation in [image] will result in a big change in the final output (due to [image])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adjustments are vector additions and subtractions, which can be thought as rotating a hyperplane such that class `0` falls on one part and class `1` falls on the other part.

Consider a `1xd` weight vector [image] indicating the weights of the perceptron model. Also, consider a `1xd` datapoint [image]. Then the predicted value of the perceptron model, considering a linear threshold without a loss of generality, will be

[image] -- Eq. 1

Here '.' is a dot product, or

[image]

The hyperplane above equation is

[image]

(Ignoring the iteration indices for the weight updates for simplicity)

Let us consider we have two classes `0` and `1`, again without a loss of generality, datapoints labelled `0` fall on one side where Eq.1 <= 0 of the hyperplane, and the datapoints labelled `1` fall on the other side where Eq.1 > 0.

The vector which is *normal* to this hyperplane is [image]. The angle between the datapoints with label `0` should be more that `90` degrees and the datapoints between the datapoints with label `1` should be less than `90` degrees.

There are three possibilities of [image] (ignoring the training rate)

- [image]: implying that this example is classified correctly by the present set of weights. Therefore we do not need any changes for the specific datapoint.
- [image] implying that the target was `1`, but the present set of weights classified it as `0`. The Eq1. [image] which was supposed to be [image]. Eq1. in this case is [image], which indicates that the angle between [image] and [image] is *greater that* `90` degrees, which should have been lesser. The update rule is [image]. If you imagine a vector addition in 2d, this will rotate the hyperplane so that the angle between [image] and [image] is closer than before and less than `90` degrees.
- [image] implying that the target was `0`, but the present set of weights classified it as `1`. The eq1. [image] which was supposed to be [image]. Eq1. in this case is [image] indicates that the angle between [image] and [image] is *lesser that* `90` degrees, which should have been greater. The update rule is [image]. Similarly this will rotate the hyperplane so that the angle between [image] and [image] is greater than `90` degrees.

This is iterated over and overe and the hyperplane is rotated and adjusted so that the angle of the hyperplane's normal has less than `90` degrees with the datapoint with class labeled `1` and greater than `90` degrees with the datapoints of class labelled `0`.

If the magnitude of [image] is huge there will be big changes, and therefore it will cause problems in the process, and may take more iterations to converge depending on the magnitude of the initial weights. Therefore it is a good idea to normalise or standardise the datapoints. From this perspective it is easy to visualise what exactly the update rules are doing visually (consider the bias as a part of the hyperplane Eq.1). Now extend this to more complicated networks and or with thresholds.

Recommended reading and reference: [Neural Network, A Systematic Introduction by Raul Rojas](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/neuron.pdf): Chapter 4

Comment: thank you so much, the vector intuition made so much sense than whatever Tom Mitchel wrote

Comment: The gradient based interpretation I think can be visualised by how the the weights proceeds in your error surface, when your dataset is not normalised. This may result in oscillations. Although I also feel the vector interpretation is much easier to understand and extend abstractly in more complex networks.

Comment: Have the same question and couldn't follow a few points in the answer. It seems to me like the angle between any datapoint and the weight vector will be less than 90 degrees. As an example, I trained a perceptron to learn the AND logic rule - so classify [0,0], [0,1], and [1,0] as 0 and [1,1] as 1. The resulting weight vector is [0.1, 0.2] and a bias of -0.2. The angle between the weight vector and each of the 4 training datapoints is less than 90 degrees because they are all in the first quadrant.

Comment: For anyone dealing with the same question as me, here is how I resolved it - think of the decision boundary as the baseline and 'extend' the weight vector so that it crosses the decision boundary at a 90 degree angle. Any point above the decision boundary (classified as a 1) will therefore have an angle of less than 90 degrees with the weight vector, and any point below the decision boundary (classified as a 0) will have an angle of more than 90 degrees with the weight vector.